# Dynamically populate one select-picker based on value in another select-picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have an html/css bootstrapped interface that looks like this:

[image]

When the user selects an option from the gray pickers on the left, I want the blue select pickers on the right to then be populated with a corresponding set of json variables.

In other words, if the user selects the "Astronomy" subject on the left, I want the blue pickers to be populated with class names like "Stars", "Planets", "Moons".

Here is how my select-pickers are set up:

```js
 <div id="course1">
               <center>
                <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-style="btn-inverse" data-size="7" data-width="300px">
        
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                var json = {
                    "courseSubject1": "Accountancy",
                    "courseSubject2": "American Studies",
                    "courseSubject3": "Anatomy & Regenerative Biology",
                    "courseSubject4": "Anesthesiology"
                  
                };

                $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                    $('.selectpicker').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + json[key] + '</option>');
                })

                  </script>
                </select>
                 
                 
                <select class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="600px">
                <option>Stars</option>
                <option>Planets</option>
                <option>Moons</option>
                </select>
```

How can I dynamically populate the blue pickers based on the option chosen in the gray pickers?

Comment: The confusing thing about your example is that both selects have the class `selectpicker` meaning your `.append` would be appending to both selects...is that what you want??

Comment: I don't want to append anything from grey to blue. If one option in grey is selected by the user, I want to append a collection of variables from a separate source. For example, if "A" is selected on the left, append collection "1" to blue. But, if "B" is selected on the left, append collection "2" to blue.

Answer (score 1):

Add a change event handler to the blue select input. When it changes it will empty the grey select, then add each new options to it:

```
$('.blue-select').on('change', function() {
  // If you want to conditionally populate your list
  // you may need to get the selected options like this:
  // $(this).find("option:selected").val()
  $('.grey-select').empty();
  $.each(json, function(key, value) {
     $('.grey-select').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
  })
});
```

Comment: I don't want the gray pickers to ever be emptied. If "Astronomy" is selected on the left, I want "Stars", "Planets", "Moons" to be available on the right. However, if "Business" is selected on the left, then I want "Economics", "Finance", "Asset MGMT" to be displayed on the right.

Comment: Do you mean the grey select has pre-existing values that you don't want removed?

Comment: Yes. The grey has pre-existing values that I never want removed. Each value in gray has a corresponding, different set of variables I want displayed in blue.